# How do I switch a new view controller in iOS development?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to write an IBAction to switch view controllers for my iPhone application:

```
-(IBAction)changeToView2:(id)sender 
{
    if (self.view2 == nil)
    {
        view2 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2Controller" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }
    self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentedViewController: view2 animated:YES];
}
```

However, I am getting a build error noting that no interface declares "presentedViewController:animated:". Why?

Changing this to "presentViewController:animated:" produces the same error.

Comment: Interestingly, XCode still notes that "no visible @interface declares the selector presentViewController:animated:" if I use that instead. Also, when I begin typing the function name, auto-complete does not mention this function name.

Comment: Also, what is 'completion:<#^(void)completion#>'? It seems as if this function has a third argument.

Comment: Is this code part of a view controller class? Or a view? Is the project navigation based? i.e. is there a navigationController?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method is `presentViewController:animated:completion:`, not `present`**ed**`ViewController:animated:`

Comment: Thank you, but XCode still notes that "no visible @interface declares the selector presentViewController:animated:".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
[self presentedViewController: view2 animated:YES];
```

try

```
[self presentViewController: view2 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you, but XCode still notes that "no visible @interface declares the selector presentViewController:animated:".

Answer (score 1):

```
[self presentViewController:view2 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you, but XCode still notes that "no visible @interface declares the selector presentViewController:animated:".

Comment: Is "self" a UIViewController?

Comment: Can you go to your header file and post the interface here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this your edited code.I think this will be helpful for you.

```
-(IBAction)changeToView2:(id)sender 
{
if (self.view2 == nil)
{
    view2 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2Controller" bundle:nil];
}
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentedViewController: view2 animated:YES];
}
```